# How to generate zip / 7z archive on the fly in a HTTP server using Gin?

Tags: go, zip, archive, httpserver

I use [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) to create a HTTP server and I want to give a dynamically generated zip archive to the user.

Theoretically I could first generate a zip file on a file system and then serve it. But that is really a bad way (to wait 5 mins before starting download). I want start giving it to a user immediately and push content as it is generated.

I've found DataFromReader ([example](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/serving-data-from-reader/)) but ContentLength is not known until archive is done.

```
func DownloadEndpoint(c *gin.Context) {
    ...
    c.DataFromReader(
        http.StatusOK,
        ContentLength,
        ContentType,
        Body,
        map[string]string{
            "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=\"archive.zip\""),
        },
    )
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use the [Stream method](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Stream) or the [ResponseWriter](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Writer) directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [stream method](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Stream) and [archive/zip](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#example_Writer) you can create zip on the fly and stream them to the server.

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "archive/zip"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
        c.Stream(func(w io.Writer) bool {

            // Create a zip archive.
            ar := zip.NewWriter(w)

            file1, _ := os.Open("filename1")
            file2, _ := os.Open("filename2")
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='filename.zip'")

            f1, _ := ar.Create("filename1")
            io.Copy(f1, file1)
            f2, _ := ar.Create("filename2")
            io.Copy(f2, file2)

            ar.Close()

            return false
        })
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

By using directly ResponseWriter

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"

    "archive/zip"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)


func main() {

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/octet-stream")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='filename.zip'")
        ar :=  zip.NewWriter(c.Writer)
        file1, _ := os.Open("filename1")
        file2, _ := os.Open("filename2")
        f1, _ := ar.Create("filename1")
        io.Copy(f1, file1)
        f2, _ := ar.Create("filename1")
        io.Copy(f1, file2)
        ar.Close()
    })
    r.Run()
}
```

Comment: Why writing the zip to a buffer when you can write it to `w`?

Comment: As @MarkusWMahlberg said, you should move the `zip.NewWriter` call to within the function closure and have it go directly to `w` without creating or using a `bytes.Buffer` or calling the final `io.Copy`. They way you have it there is no point streaming since the compression is fully completed in memory before writing anything to HTTP connection.

Comment: It makes sense to use the `io.writer` provided by the stream closure to create the zip archive

Comment: Works fine for me, thank you! By the way, there is a small error in the code, I think we should use `filename=\"filename.zip\"` instead of `filename='filename.zip'`.